# uwp file access permission extension for video playlists

Tags: uwp, media-player, windows-10-universal, playlist, file-access

I know about all rules of uwp file access permissions. and I also know about MostRecentlyUsedList and FutureAccessList ( 1000 limit ) as well.

I am developing a video player app in which I need to **create video playlists**.

I tried to do it with **PlayList class**, it works as far as the video files included in playlists are from within **"VideoLibrary"** hence accessible by the app.

If even one of the files ( picked by the user and then saved in the playlist ) is from a folder which isn't included in video library, then while I try **Playlist.LoadAsync(StorageFile)** I get an exception of **Access Denied** //StorageFile here is the **.wpl** file , or should I say the already saved playlist file.

The **PlaylistFile** is actually within the **VideoLibrary** so it is directly accessible by the app, so it loads normally and saved into a **StorageFile** object normally, but when I supply that object to **Playlist.LoadAsync**, access is denied, because the video file in that **playlist** was outside the videolibrary, when my user picked it with **fileopenpicker**.

**So**

**1.** I want to know what can be the solution because I want to include all video files in video library and all those files which user has selected in the past, to be available and use able by the playlists.

**2.** I can use **futureaccesslist** to create history for my app ofcourse, but can they be used **(tokens)** in Playlist class? I think not. because it only accepts **Collection of Storage Files**. **Even** if I can use some sort of **database** approach to achieve a **playlist functionality** with **futureaccesslist** tokens, Yes I can do that but it still has limit of **1000**

**Summary :** I need a clean way so that I can use all video files present on my user's system to be available for him to play, add in history and work well with playlist and stuff. without limit of 1000.

**Thanks in advance.**

**Note : ** maybe I can do it by prompting user to select their whole PC/Root directory for access to whole system? but I dont think that is a good approach also because my uwp app is support to run on all windows 10 devices.

Comment: Asking for the access to the entire device or drive might go against security guidelines and frown upon in a store application. However, it looks like it will be well within your application mode of operation to ask the user to give you access to the selected folders (besides VideoLibrary) where video files are stored instead of asking for each individual file access. Would this work for you?

Comment: Yes @DK that would work for me and I have tried that as well, but still if a user selects to play a file which is outside of the video library and then he wants to add it into the playlist, that feature wont be possible, because for example use only has a single file on desktop and he doesnt want to add desktop to video library, but he plays that file with my app and then while playing he wants to add it to a playlist. is there a way I can workaround for this specific feature/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I can use futureaccesslist to create history for my app ofcourse, but can they be used (tokens) in Playlist class?

When we add the file to the [`FutureAccessList`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.accesscache.storageitemaccesslist), then we do not need use the token in the `PlayList`. It can read the file by Playlist.LoadAsync and does not throw Access Denied.

As you known, this list can store up to 1000 items and must be maintained by the app. If you want to access more than 1000 files, you should copy the files to the The locations that all apps can access. For example the VideosLibrary, you can [File access permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/file-access-permissions).

Comment: so do you mean I can let user pick a file outsite the video library save that file in Playlist object, and when later on when the user runs the app again, that file can be accessed and played easily with PlaylistLoadAsync ?

Comment: Yes, we can use the playlists file when the user runs the app again. You can test the [Playlists sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/Playlists). We should be able to add picked files to FutureAccessList by `foreach (var item in files)
{
  string faToken = Windows.Storage.AccessCache.StorageApplicationPermissions.FutureAccessList.Add(item);
}` in the PickAudioButton_Click event 
 in Scenario1_Create.xaml.cs

Comment: No I actually meant that when can user pick multiple files -> store them into playlists and then when the app runs again that playlist can be accessed and played again? I mean is that type of access possible? without touching the "FutureAccessList" at all

Comment: If user pick multiple files and add the file to `FutureAccessList` by first time, we can run again that playlist can be accessed and played again without  use `FutureAccessList`. If not, it will throw `Access Denied`.